# Python disable webbrowser in order to let it fails

Tags: python, linux

I am working on a mediacenter OSMC linux box where there is python. I am using an application called flyckrsmartsync used to sync up my Flickr account with a folder on my mediacenter. The python app must be authenticated on Flickr. I installed on another linux box where no browser where configured. The app showed me the url I can use on my Windows box to authenticate the app.

On my OMC box the local browser is activated and I am not able to show the URL in the console.

Basically the webbrowser.get() method that fails in first linux box and let appear the URL does not fail on second linux box and then it hangs once he enter in the browser.

If I do on second box the command "python":

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Aug 13 2016, 17:56:53)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Then the following command:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser._tryorder
['www-browser', 'lynx']
```

Is there a way to unregister in python all the browser so that the webbrowser.get api fails?
Is there a why to add them again later once I authenticated the app?

Comment: Well, you can always build a module that has a `get` function that does nothing, passes all other functions along to `webbrowser`, and then use this new module as a drop-in replacement. That aside, why not use Dropbox, Google Drive, etc, to store and sync the images?

Comment: I want my photos on my Media Center because sometime I could see them on my TV without have any PC to turn on. My media center is always available next to the TV. I have my photos in Flickr but slideshow is now fast when it starts. Have a copy on local protect also my photo to be resized by provider. This happened to me with PicasaWeb that a some point changed terms and condition and reduced the size of all my photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the simple

```
del webbrowser._tryorder[:]
```

This might not be portable - `_tryorder` is not documented, and it starts with `_` which means that it is private to the module.

Example:

```
Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14) 
[GCC 6.2.0 20160927] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.get()
<webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser object at 0x7f9e91773c88>
>>> del webbrowser._tryorder[:]
>>> webbrowser.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/webbrowser.py", line 51, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```